# Dropdown menu not working on Android

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu working perfect on iphone but not on HTC or android phones.

See if I've missed something or if I should edit.

```
   <select name="select_page" id="select_page" class="select_page" data-mini="true" data-theme="c">

    <?php
    $pageID = 5;
        $subpages = get_pages( array(
        'child_of' => $pageID,
        'sort_order' => 'asc',
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order') );
    ?>        

    <?php if($post->post_parent) {?>
      <option value="<?php echo get_page_link($pageID) ?>" >Startpage</option>
    <?php } else {?>
      <option value="<?php echo get_page_link($pageID) ?>" selected="selected">Startpage</option>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php                                  
    foreach($subpages as $page) { $i++;
      $pages[] += $page->ID;        
    ?>
    <?php if($page->post_title == get_the_title()) {?>
      <option value="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $i.'. '.$page->post_title ?></option>
    <?php } else {?>
      <option value="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>"><?php echo $i.'. '.$page->post_title ?></option>  <?php } ?>
    <?php }?> 

    </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you always open and close the php statements again and again? For example, instead of

```
<?php if($post->post_parent) {?>
  <option value="<?php echo get_page_link($pageID) ?>" >Startpage</option>
<?php } else {?>
  <option value="<?php echo get_page_link($pageID) ?>" selected="selected">Startpage</option>
<?php } ?>
```

I would suggest

```
  <?php
      if($post->post_parent) {
        echo "<option value=\"get_page_link($pageID)\">Startpage</option>\n";
      } else {
        echo "<option value=\"get_page_link($pageID)\" selected=\"selected\">Startpage</option>\n";
      }
  ?>
```

etc. etc.

Comment: Dont know actually I just do it. I guess its my style of writing. So you mean that would solve the problem ?

Comment: well, actually your "style of writing" is incorrect, in the example both `option value` lines will be displayed in the source code of the html page and this is not what you like, is it? Just take a look at the source code with Firebug or another developer tool...

Comment: Allright , then ill take a look at it. And do it the "right" way. Its a mobile site dont think its as important as a website. But good information about the source code thou, ill think about next time. But should it solve the problem by the way  ? :)

Comment: additionally you can use a validator to validate your html ... http://validator.w3.org/